Android ConstraintLayout - adjust width of Childs
I need to have a composition which dynamically adjusts child view width depending on available space.
Rules:

Right and Left dividers always visible
Dividers size: min 6dp, max 16dp
Dividers can adjust its size due to text size.
Text is single line and might ellipse if does not fix between the dividers.

These are the different behaviour variants I need from the composition.

I have the following code, but dividers do not have the same size when text overflows its space:
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    val minLineWidth = 3.dp
    val maxLineWidth = 16.dp

    val idLeft = "line_left"
    val idRight = "line_right"
    val idText = "text"

    val constraint = ConstraintSet {
        val startLineRef = createRefFor(idLeft)
        val endLineRef = createRefFor(idRight)
        val textRef = createRefFor(idText)

        constrain(startLineRef) {
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(textRef.start)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atLeast(minLineWidth).atMost(maxLineWidth)
        }

        constrain(endLineRef) {
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            start.linkTo(textRef.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atLeast(minLineWidth).atMost(maxLineWidth)
        }

        constrain(textRef) {
            start.linkTo(startLineRef.end)
            end.linkTo(endLineRef.start)
            width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atMostWrapContent
        }

    }
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.requiredWidth(80.dp),
        constraintSet = constraint,
    ) {
        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId(idLeft),
            color = Color.Red
        )

        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId(idRight),
            color = Color.Blue
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId(idText),
            text = "ABCDEFG",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )
    }
}

Result:

Suggestions to have divider to always have the same size when shrinking due to text size?
